# @keydown and @input firing together

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am working on a component in a vue application that takes a passcode that is 8 digits each digit has its own input when types a character in, it should move to the next input, if the user deletes the character if it can the focus should move to the previous sibling, if the user presses the left or right key, the focus should move with the key press. What is happening at the moment is that the @input and @keydown event are both firing, so if the the user presses left and the the previous sibling already has content, it moves the focus back to the right.

Here is my code,

```
<div class="code">
  <input autofocus type="text" maxlength="1" class="passcode__box" @input="handleInput" @keydown="handleKeyDown"/>
  <input type="text" class="passcode__box" maxlength="1" @input="handleInput" @keydown="handleKeyDown"/>
  <input type="text" class="passcode__box" maxlength="1" @keyup="handleInput" @keydown="handleKeyDown"/>
  <input type="text" class="passcode__box" maxlength="1" @keyup="handleInput" @keydown="handleKeyDown"/>
  <input type="text" class="passcode__box" maxlength="1" @keyup="handleInput" @keydown="handleKeyDown"/>
  <input type="text" class="passcode__box" maxlength="1" @keyup="handleInput" @keydown="handleKeyDown"/>
  <input type="text" class="passcode__box" maxlength="1" @keyup="handleInput" @keydown="handleKeyDown"/>
  <input type="text" class="passcode__box" maxlength="1" @keyup="handleInput" @keydown="handleKeyDown"/>
</div>
```

and the 2 methods,

```
handleInput(event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  const nextElement = event.target.nextElementSibling;
  if (value === "" || !nextElement) {
    return;
  }
  nextElement.focus();

},

  handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log('handleKeyDown');
    //Right arrow key
    if(event.keyCode == 39) {
      event.target.nextElementSibling.focus();
    }

    //Left arrow key
    if(event.keyCode == 37) {
      event.target.previousElementSibling.focus();
    }

    //Backspace key - cmd
    if(event.keyCode == 8) { //backspace
      if(event.target.value === '') {
        event.target.previousElementSibling.focus();
        return;
      }
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }
```

Here is an example of the component, that wierdly uses the same code [enter link description here](https://2v4ou.csb.app/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in the `@keyup` events, because `@keyup` emits after `@input`. You can read more about KeyboardEvents and their sequences in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

Anyway I took the liberty of  rewriting/refactoring the code you provided and introduced a couple of JS-shenanigans. The idea is the same though. There is a working example [on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-keydown-and-input-firing-together-pui6c).

Hope this helped!

```html
<template>
  <div class="passcode">
    <template v-for="index in inputs">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="passcode__box"
        :key="index"
        :maxlength="maxlength"
        @keydown="onKeydown"
        @input="onInput"
      >
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
export const KeyCodes = {
  RIGHT_ARROW: 39,
  LEFT_ARROW: 37,
  BACKSPACE: 8
};

export default {
  name: "Passcode",

  props: {
    inputs: {
      type: Number,
      default: 4
    },
    maxlength: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
    }
  },

  methods: {
    /**
     * Moves focus between siblings and handles `Backspace`.
     *
     * @param {KeyboardEvent} event
     */
    onKeydown(event) {
      const target = event.target;
      const next = target.nextElementSibling;
      const prev = target.previousElementSibling;

      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case KeyCodes.RIGHT_ARROW:
          next && next.focus();
          break;

        case KeyCodes.LEFT_ARROW:
          prev && prev.focus();
          break;

        case KeyCodes.BACKSPACE:
          if (target.value.length) {
            target.value = "";
            return;
          }

          setTimeout(() => prev && prev.focus());
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    },

    /**
     * Handles printable characters and moves focus
     * to the next <input> sibling if it's present.
     *
     * @param {KeyboardEvent} event
     */
    onInput(event) {
      const value = event.target.value;
      const next = event.target.nextElementSibling;

      if (!value.length || !next) {
        return;
      }

      next.focus();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```